# Querying Sitecore Content Item Data Fields With Spaces in Data Field Name

Tags: sitecore

Please be gentle...I'm very new to Sitecore development.

So the following returns the value from any data field associated with a content item...as long as the data field name has no spaces in it

```
    #foreach($item in $genie.QueryPageItems("/sitecore/content/Sparklev2/articles/*"))
       $item.Name - $item.Copyright - $item.Body Tag Css 
    #end
```

and the method it is calling (written by another developer):

```
    public List<PageItem> QueryPageItems(string query){
        return (from item in Sitecore.Context.Database.SelectItems(query).ToList<Item>() select new PageItem(item)).ToList<PageItem>();
    }
```

The above returns the name and the copyright fine, but not the body tag css values. I have wrapped body tag css in everything I could think of but cannot make this work. Am I missing something or is this just not possilbe

Comment: What is the view engine/framework you are using for the first code snippet? It's not C# or Razor...

Comment: That looks like a velocity template, which is weird as thats Java. If it is you could do `$item.get('Body Tag Css')`

Comment: looks like a custom PageItem class, you should check how that class processes the item and fields. Maybe add a property which you can supply a value in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks all. Robert, turns out it's NVelocity and from the research I've done, the syntax for Velocity and NVelocity should be the same, but $item.get('Body Tag Css') doesn't work. Nothing like having a short timeline and a handful of new technologies to pick up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape special characters and space.

`/sitecore/content/#Sparkle V2#/articles/*`

On a separate note; it's gonna perform donkeys. But escaping is your answer.

Comment: See also: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2012/05/sitecore-query-cheat-sheet.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Mark. The portion that isn't working isn't sparklev2...that's an unbroken string. The problem is with $item.Body Tag Css. I'd already tried escaping as you'd suggested, but that doesn't alleviate the issue.

Comment: Oh. I misread your question, apologies. For what  you're asking, you'd be better off tagging this article with the front end framework you're using - as it isn't something very many Sitecore developers will know - nor is the problem particularly sitecore related.